# Getting certain attribute value using XPath

Tags: python, xpath

From the following HTML snippet:

```
<link rel="index" href="/index.php" />
<link rel="contents" href="/getdata.php" />
<link rel="copyright" href="/blabla.php" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/all/favicon.ico" />
```

I'm trying to get the `href` value of the `link` tag with rel value = `"shortcut icon"`, I'm trying to achieve that using XPath.

How to do that in Python?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Like this:

```
data = """<link rel="index" href="/index.php" />
<link rel="contents" href="/getdata.php" />
<link rel="copyright" href="/blabla.php" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/all/favicon.ico" />
"""

from lxml import etree

d = etree.HTML(data)

d.xpath('//link[@rel="shortcut icon"]/@href')
['/img/all/favicon.ico']
```

Comment: how to get the value of a tag in XML, not attribute value'