# Attributes in Xpath local-name()

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xpath

This is a small sample of my xml file.

```
<w:p xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
   <w:pPr>
      <w:rPr>
         <w:highlight w:val="yellow"/>
      </w:rPr>
   </w:pPr>
   <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
   <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
   <w:r w:rsidRPr="00D1434D">
      <w:rPr>
         <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman"
                   w:eastAsia="MS PGothic"
                   w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
         <w:b/>
         <w:color w:val="000000"/>
         <w:sz w:val="24"/>
         <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
         <w:highlight w:val="yellow"/>
      </w:rPr>
      <w:t xml:space="preserve">Responses to </w:t>
   </w:r>
   <w:r w:rsidR="00335D4A" w:rsidRPr="00D1434D">
      <w:rPr>
         <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman"
                   w:eastAsia="MS PGothic"
                   w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
         <w:b/>
         <w:color w:val="000000"/>
         <w:sz w:val="24"/>
         <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
         <w:highlight w:val="yellow"/>
         <w:lang w:eastAsia="ja-JP"/>
      </w:rPr>
      <w:t>the Reviewer</w:t>
   </w:r>
</w:p>
```

I want to extract text with the `w:highlight` tag specifically having the attribute `value` = **"yellow"** . I searched for it but wasn't able to come up with a solution.

The following works for highlight in general:

```
for t in source.xpath('.//*[local-name()="highlight"]/../..//*[local-name()="t"]'):
     do something
```

I tried :

```
for t in lxml_tree.xpath('//*[local-name()="highlight"][@val="yellow"]/../..//*[local-name()="t"]'):
```

this doesn't work, returns nothing..

Comment: For future questions, make sure your XML is _properly formatted_ and readable (an incredibly long line is not). Also, the `w:` prefix was not declared and your XML snippet not well-formed because `</w:p>` was missing.

Comment: how is xml data formatted on SO??

Comment: this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243131/getting-certain-attribute-value-using-xpath) was somewhat similar , but it doesn't work on local-name().

Comment: You can't format it automatically. Either do it manually or e.g. perform an XSLT identity transform that properly indents the XML.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`w:val` attribute is in namespace, so you can't just address it by `@val`. One possible solution is by using `@*[local-name()='attribute name']` expression to address an attribute by it's local name, similar to what you've done for elements :

```
//*[local-name()="highlight"][@*[local-name()='val' and .='yellow']]/../..//*[local-name()="t"]
```

Comment: How about using `following::` instead of `/../..//`? See http://xsltransform.net/bdxtpQ.

Comment: could you explain your answer? i did not understand what @* does and "and .="

Comment: @Swordy `@*` means any attribute, similar to `//*` which means any element. `.` refer to current context, which in that particular usage is the value of the attribute referred by `@*`

Comment: @MathiasMüller using following extracts text without highlights too.. I used it on the entire xml .

Comment: @Swordy It would - if not for the structure of OOXML documents. The first `w:t` that follows after `w:highlight` is always the highlighted text.

Comment: @har07 I had to switch over to findall because I needed to add a space after every p tag . I have a problem with findall that i cannot specify the attribute value..