# xmllint unable to read attribute values

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath, xml-namespaces, xmllint

Experts of `xmllint`, please help me in extracting an XML tag value based on xpath with an attribute.

Sample XML as follow:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Body>
        <wd:Get_Integration_Events_Response wd:version="v35.0" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
            <wd:Response_Data>
                <wd:Integration_Event>
                    <wd:Background_Process_Instance_Data>
                        <wd:Background_Process_Instance_Status_Reference wd:Descriptor="Completed">
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">d8b0bcd8446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            **<wd:ID wd:type="Background_Process_Instance_Status_ID">Completed</wd:ID>**
                        </wd:Background_Process_Instance_Status_Reference>
                    </wd:Background_Process_Instance_Data>
                </wd:Integration_Event>
            </wd:Response_Data>
        </wd:Get_Integration_Events_Response>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I am trying to extract the value `Completed` as highlighted from the row.
Without name space values, the command should be something like this:

```
xmllint --xpath "string(//Envelope/Body/Get_Integration_Events_Response/Response_Data/Integration_Event/Background_Process_Instance_Data/Background_Process_Instance_Status_Reference/ID[@type='Background_Process_Instance_Status_ID'])" example.xml
```

My actual command is as follows:

```
xmllint --xpath "string(//*[local-name()='Envelope' and namespace-uri()='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='Get_Integration_Events_Response']/*[local-name()='Response_Data']/*[local-name()='Integration_Event']/*[local-name()='Background_Process_Instance_Data']/*[local-name()='Background_Process_Instance_Status_Reference']/*[local-name()='ID']['@type=Background_Process_Instance_Status_ID'])" example.xml
```

This is returning value `d8b0bcd8446c11de98360015c5e6daf6` but not `Completed`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
['@type=Background_Process_Instance_Status_ID']
```

with

```
[@*[local-name()='type' and .='Background_Process_Instance_Status_ID']]
```

Command:

```
xmllint --xpath "string(//*[local-name()='Envelope' and namespace-uri()='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='Get_Integration_Events_Response']/*[local-name()='Response_Data']/*[local-name()='Integration_Event']/*[local-name()='Background_Process_Instance_Data']/*[local-name()='Background_Process_Instance_Status_Reference']/*[local-name()='ID'][@*[local-name()='type' and .='Background_Process_Instance_Status_ID']])" example.xml
```

Output:

```
Completed
```

---

See: [Attributes in Xpath local-name()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26438417/3776858)

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Any help on how to direct the xmllint command to a string variable instead of a physical file?

Comment: I suggest `variable="$(xmllint ... 2>&1)"` to redirect stderr to stdout and then to your variable.