# Xpath collect links from and to

Tags: css, web-scraping, xpath

There is an html code, something like this

```
<strong>Link group name 1</strong>
<br>
<a> Link_1 </a>
<a> Link_2 </a>
<a> Link_3 </a>
<br>
<strong>Link group name 2</strong>
<a> Link_1 </a>
<a> Link_2 </a>
<br>
<br>
<strong>Link group nameк 3</strong>
<a> Link_1 </a>
```

I need to print this data in this form:

```
Link group name 1 - Link_1
Link group name 1 - Link_2
Link group name 1 - Link_3

Link group name 2 - Link_1
Link group name 2 - Link_2

Link group name 3 - Link_1
```

is it possible to implement this using xpath, or how to capture, for example, all links between certain , or let's say capture all links up to the first  that comes along?

I'm trying to do this, but it doesn't work, and probably it will collect everything and after strong

```
for model in item.css('strong'):
    print(model.css('::text').get(), model.xpath(f'/following-sibling::a[1]/@href').extract())
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which scripting language you use, but try something like this:

```
for a in item.xpath('//a'):
    print(a.xpath('preceding-sibling::strong[1]').text_content(), " - ", a.text_content())
```

Comment: @siebe-jongebloedI use Python

Comment: Did you you try the answer?

Comment: I'm trying print(a.xpath('preceding brother::strong[1]/text()').get()) and it works, but how do I add the href value to this expression?

Comment: Your html-example does not show the @href. In order to understand what you exactly expect, please change your question. To us a attribute i.e use  a.xpath("/@href"). See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2243186/3710053